# android overlay images whitch are download by asynctask in a imageview

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, overlay

I want to download many images with `AsyncTask`, and put them into an `imageView` - overlaying many images in an imageView.

I used the `LayerDrawable`, but I can't do it very well, because I must use the method `imageView.setImageDrawable()` in the AsyncTask.

I want to use the canvas to draw images in the `imageView` but I can`t know how to do it.

If you have answer, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: why don't you want LayerDrawable? you can use imageView.setImageDrawable(LayerDrawable) also

Comment: because: First, I will download many images with asyncTask. Second, put images into a layerDrawable. Third, use imageView.setImageDrawable(LayerDrawable). And run it, there is a nullException when imageView.setImageDrawable(LayerDrawable)

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's hard to know exactly what your problem is, but I can talk about a general pattern for displaying downloaded images. The first step, which you have already done, is to do the actual downloads in an `AsyncTask` so that it doesn't block the UI thread and the application remains responsive. However, since the downloads are taking place on a different thread, you cannot update any UI elements during the `AsyncTask`; UI elements may only be modified from the UI thread. To get around this, you'll want to store the data you got from your web requests, either on the `AsyncTask` object or by returning it, and use the result in `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method. In that method you should be able to safely call `setImageDrawable`. For more on how to use `AsyncTask`, including details about the generics used in the declaration of it and passing around results, I'd suggest glancing over the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

From your comments, it sounds like you may not be properly saving off the `ImageView` that you are trying to set the drawable of, causing a null pointer exception. You should double check that the variable you are reading from has been set. If this doesn't address your problem, you'll probably need to post source code for the class that you're having a problem with.

Comment: Thank you, I will use another thinking to slove the problem.